# What are the preferred MySQL column data types for CodeIgniter 4's created_at, updated_at, and deleted_at field definitions?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, timestamp, codeigniter-4

I want to use CodeIgniter 4's Models' ability to automatically set the `created_at`, `updated_at`, and `deleted_at` fields in database tables.

For that, should I set those fields as `TIMESTAMP` in MySQL or `DATETIME`?

If I set them as `TIMESTAMP`, I know that they will record the real-time regardless of the timezone, but the `deleted_at` column cannot be null. On the other hand, if I set them as `DATETIME`, I am not sure if CodeIgniter will store the time in *'UTC'* or in the server's time, which may not be *'UTC'*.

Comment: And the question is ....?  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: The question is if `created_at`, `updated_at` and `deleted_at` should be `timestamp` or `datetime` in MySQL so as to use them with CodeIgniter 4's built in functions to handle them.

Comment: I vote for `TIMESTAMP`, but cannot help you with CodeIgniter.  I see lots of tables with columns like those, but I rarely see anyone using those columns.  So I do question whether you will ever use any of them.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `TIMESTAMP`, however, working with date-time objects is always a pain. It's a matter of if you want it the data to be human readable in your database I think. Since `deleted_at` cant be `NULL` setting its default value to either super far in the past or super far in the future will allow you to run checks.  ie

`if deleted_at != DISTANT_DATETIME run xyz`

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever think to use a Unix Time Stamp (epoch time), saving at `bigint` or `varchar` column definition?

Using the CodeIgniter Model you can validate insert, update and delete actions to affect as desired.

When getting the record is more easy to convert using `DateTime` PHP class, like:

```php
$dt = new DateTime($row->created_at);
print $dt->format("m, d/Y H:i:s");
```

But if you want to use `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP`, my suggestion is

- `created_at` : TIMESTAMP, this will store
- `updated_at` : DATETIME, but
  you must control when to save, and be aware that is going to get the
  time zone reference
- `deleted_at` : DATETIME, same specs as `updated_at`

Take this as advice:

> The DATETIME type is used for values that contain both date and time parts. MySQL retrieves and displays DATETIME values in 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss' format. The supported range is '1000-01-01 00:00:00' to '9999-12-31 23:59:59'.
>
> The TIMESTAMP data type is used for values that contain both date and time parts. TIMESTAMP has a range of '1970-01-01 00:00:01' **UTC** to '2038-01-19 03:14:07' **UTC**.

Check this [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html)

Answer (score 0):

#### Background Information

[Every time CodeIgniter runs](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/extending/core_classes.html#creating-core-system-classes), there are several base classes that are initialized automatically as part of the core framework. One of which is the `CodeIgniter\CodeIgniter` system class.

In this particular class, a default timezone used by all date/time functions on your server ([`date_default_timezone_set`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)) and a default runtime locale ([`Locale::setDefault`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/locale.setdefault.php)) are set.

[Excerpt from the `CodeIgniter\CodeIgniter` system class](https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/blob/c546e21c4e1570f870bc9a7976755f1d5232745c/system/CodeIgniter.php#L193)

```php
public function initialize()
{
    // ...

    // Set default locale on the server
    Locale::setDefault($this->config->defaultLocale ?? 'en');

    // Set default timezone on the server
    date_default_timezone_set($this->config->appTimezone ?? 'UTC');

    $this->initializeKint();
}
```

If you look closely enough, the application's *'locale'* and *'timezone'* settings are primarily based on what you defined in the `app/Config/App.php` configuration file or in the [`.env` environment variable file](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/configuration.html?highlight=env#environment-variables-and-codeigniter) that resides at the root of your project.

**Excerpt from the `app/Config/App.php` configuration file.**

[Default Locale](https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/blob/c546e21c4e1570f870bc9a7976755f1d5232745c/app/Config/App.php#L64) and [Application Timezone](https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/blob/c546e21c4e1570f870bc9a7976755f1d5232745c/app/Config/App.php#L101)

```php
    /**
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     * Default Locale
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     *
     * The Locale roughly represents the language and location that your visitor
     * is viewing the site from. It affects the language strings and other
     * strings (like currency markers, numbers, etc), that your program
     * should run under for this request.
     */
    public string $defaultLocale = 'en';

    // ...

    /**
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     * Application Timezone
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     *
     * The default timezone that will be used in your application to display
     * dates with the date helper, and can be retrieved through app_timezone()
     */
    public string $appTimezone = 'UTC';
```

---

So, to answer your inquiry,

- OP's inquiry:

> ... I am not sure if CodeIgniter will store the time in UTC or in the
> server's time, which may not be UTC.

**Answer:** That will depend on your app timezone setting in the `app/Config/App.php` configuration file or in the [`.env` environment variable file](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/configuration.html?highlight=env#environment-variables-and-codeigniter) that resides at the root of your project. By default, the [`$appTimezone` property is set to 'UTC'](https://codeigniter4.github.io/CodeIgniter4/installation/upgrade_430.html#config).

---

#### Additional Explanation

With the background information out of the way, if you want to inform CodeIgniter 4 to automatically set the `created_at` and `updated_at` fields in addition to the `deleted_at` field for [soft deleted records](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/models/model.html?highlight=soft%20delete#usesoftdeletes), you need to override the `$useTimestamps` property on your [Model](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/models/model.html?highlight=soft%20delete#configuring-your-model) and set it to `true`.

[`$useTimestamps`](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/models/model.html?highlight=soft%20delete#usetimestamps)

> This boolean value determines whether the current date is
> automatically added to all inserts and updates. If true, will set the
> current time in the format specified by [`$dateFormat`](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/models/model.html?highlight=soft%20delete#dateformat). This requires
> that the table have columns named `created_at`, `updated_at` and
> `deleted_at` in the appropriate data type.

These fields/columns (`created_at`, `updated_at` & `deleted_at`) are automatically filled/set when you call the following methods on your Model instance:

1. [`->save(...)`](https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/blob/c546e21c4e1570f870bc9a7976755f1d5232745c/system/BaseModel.php#L683).
2. [`->insert(...)`](https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/blob/c546e21c4e1570f870bc9a7976755f1d5232745c/system/Model.php#L708).
3. [`->insertBatch(...)`](https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/blob/c546e21c4e1570f870bc9a7976755f1d5232745c/system/BaseModel.php#L818).
4. [`->update(...)`](https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/blob/c546e21c4e1570f870bc9a7976755f1d5232745c/system/Model.php#L742).
5. [`->updateBatch(...)`](https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/blob/c546e21c4e1570f870bc9a7976755f1d5232745c/system/BaseModel.php#L968).
6. [`->delete(...)`](https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/blob/c546e21c4e1570f870bc9a7976755f1d5232745c/system/BaseModel.php#L1042).

---

Now, coming back to your question,

- OP's question:

> For that, should I set those fields as `timestamp` in MySQL or `datetime`?

**Response:**

Firstly, at the time of writing this post, CodeIgniter 4 supports 3 formats by default, namely:

1. 'datetime'. I.e: 'Y-m-d H:i:s'.
2. 'date'. I.e: 'Y-m-d'.
3. 'int'. I.e: (a PHP timestamp).

[`$dateFormat`](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/models/model.html?highlight=soft%20delete#dateformat)

> This value works with `$useTimestamps` and `$useSoftDeletes` to ensure
> that the correct type of date value gets inserted into the database.
> By default, this creates `DATETIME` values, but valid options are:
> `'datetime'`, `'date'`, or `'int'` (a PHP timestamp). Using
> **useSoftDeletes** or **useTimestamps** with an invalid or missing dateFormat will cause an exception.

With the linked resource above, CodeIgniter 4 expects the fields (`created_at`, `updated_at` & `deleted_at`) to have a [`DATETIME`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html) data type. To supplement on this, one of [CodeIgniter 4's official packages](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/official_packages.html) called [CodeIgniter Shield](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/official_packages.html#shield) also uses `DATETIME` as it's preferred column data type for theses specific fields.

[Excerpt from Shield's `Database/Migrations/2020-12-28-223112_create_auth_tables.php` file](https://github.com/codeigniter4/shield/blob/e48f15d658262956d0beea8019e07bd5caeae276/src/Database/Migrations/2020-12-28-223112_create_auth_tables.php#L27)

```php
public function up(): void
{
    // Users Table
    $this->forge->addField([
        // ...
        'last_active'    => ['type' => 'datetime', 'null' => true],
        'created_at'     => ['type' => 'datetime', 'null' => true],
        'updated_at'     => ['type' => 'datetime', 'null' => true],
        'deleted_at'     => ['type' => 'datetime', 'null' => true],
    ]);
    $this->forge->addPrimaryKey('id');
    $this->forge->addUniqueKey('username');
    $this->forge->createTable($this->tables['users']);

// ...
}
```

[CodeIgniter Settings](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/official_packages.html#settings), another official package also uses `DATETIME` as it's preferred column data type for these specific fields.

[Excerpt from Settings's `Database/Migrations/2021-07-04-041948_CreateSettingsTable.php` file](https://github.com/codeigniter4/settings/blob/95adbf17b49c5274c6ce52b22a75a34533849fdf/src/Database/Migrations/2021-07-04-041948_CreateSettingsTable.php#L21)

```php
public function up()
{
    $this->forge->addField('id');
    $this->forge->addField([
    // ...
        'created_at' => [
            'type' => 'datetime',
            'null' => false,
        ],
        'updated_at' => [
            'type' => 'datetime',
            'null' => false,
        ],
    ]);
    $this->forge->createTable($this->config->database['table'], true);
}
```

---

#### Important notes:

1. The `deleted_at` field must be nullable. In addition, it is expected to have a column data type of either `DATETIME` or `INTEGER`.

[$useSoftDeletes](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/models/model.html?highlight=soft%20delete#usesoftdeletes)

> If true, then any `delete()` method calls will set `deleted_at` in the
> database, instead of actually deleting the row. This can preserve data
> when it might be referenced elsewhere, or can maintain a “recycle bin”
> of objects that can be restored, or even simply preserve it as part of
> a security trail. If true, the **find*()** methods will only return
> non-deleted rows, unless the `withDeleted()` method is called prior to
> calling the **find*()** method.
>
> This requires either a `DATETIME` or `INTEGER` field in the database
> as per the model’s `$dateFormat` setting. The default field name is
> `deleted_at` however this name can be configured to any name of your
> choice by using `$deletedField` property.
>
> Important
>
> The `deleted_at` field must be nullable.

Answer (score 0):

TIMESTAMP can only store dates up to '2038-01-19 03:14:07' UTC. To avoid bugs or a database migration in the near future, you definitely want to use DATETIME.
Source: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html